# How to access home-built server with ILO

Tags: hp, remote-access, ilo

I have used ILO ports before but have recently built a home server that I want to access using ILO ports, is this possible? If so do I need to just find one that plugs in or is there special ones for this use case?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are looking for a way to perform out-of-band management on your server using something similar to HP's iLO. (Dell calls it DRAC and other's call it IPMI)

In my own personal experience, I've only every found one way to so such a thing on a single system by using a KVMoIP device from Lantronix called a Spider KVM.

https://www.lantronix.com/products/lantronix-spider/

https://www.lantronix.com/products/lantronix-spiderduo/

This is in no way an endorsement of that product, it's just the only one I've seen for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of the Spider KVM. It's definitely useful, however the iLO provides a bit more. Like you can mount ISO/virtualUSB devices from your computer or from URL and you get basic status of the HW and it's components. But I understand, that isn't possible to realize, without support from the motherboard and BIOS(UEFI).

Comment: The Spider KVM and most other KVMoIP devices do indeed support virtual CD/USB functions. You can also power the Spider via an external source to allow BIOS level access to your system. The new version of the Spider KVM also has an optional power-module that allows remote power resets as well.

It does not provide the means for H/W monitoring as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no such option how to connect iLO to standard PC. iLO modules are intended for usage with HPE HW, which is prepared for iLO connection and BIOSes support it.

Comment: Is there alternatives that I could use?